# Why this async aiohttp is so slow/How to speed it up

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I adapted aiohttp code pretty directly from [this post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/making-concurrent-web-api-requests-in-python-i-recommend-aiohttp-43f2d46ef4da#a209) to create a scrip which I am aiming to query my database 40+ times a second so I can benchmark its throttling. This seems reasonable based on the benchmarks in the article for the section of code I adapted, but my actual results are far poorer (barely breaking 4 queries a second).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import datetime. 
TOKEN = [REDACTED]
API_URL = [REDACTED]. 

queries = 40
succ_queries = 0
throttled = False

async def query_api(session):
    global throttled, succ_queries
    async with session.get(API_URL, headers={'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(TOKEN)}) as resp:
        content = await resp.text()
        #print(content)
        if "Request was throttled." in content:
            throttled = True
        succ_queries += 1
        return resp

async def by_aiohttp_concurrency(total: int):
    # code from https://levelup.gitconnected.com/making-concurrent-web-api-requests-in-python-i-recommend-aiohttp-43f2d46ef4da#a209

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [] 
        for _ in range(total):
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(query_api(session)))

        original_result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        #for res in original_result:
            #print(res)


        
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
asyncio.run(by_aiohttp_concurrency(queries))
print("--- It took ", (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time), " seconds to run ", succ_queries, " queries ---").
```

As of now, I'm usually only getting 40 queries in around 9 seconds so I'm really hoping someone can help me out in speeding this up.
Strangely enough, when I tested this same script with [a URL not on my dev server](http://httpbin.org/ip) I get much better speed, but I thought my code as it stands shouldn't be waiting for server response before sending more queries so I must be fundamentally confused on some level

Comment: maybe all problem is in server. Maybe server can't run more queries, maybe it has some limit. Some APIs have limits for number of quesies per second. And if server has limits then you can't it make faster - maybe it need to pay for bigger limit. You didn't show URL for this server so we can't check it in documentation or test with your code.

Comment: @furas is definitely onto something.  While most public facing servers are multithreaded, some servers are single threaded and can only handle one request at a time.  The behavior you're describing fits this almost perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, further testing seems to confirm your points @furas and Frank_Yellin . Thanks!